# Docker-compose and docker file versions - differences and interferences

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I couldn't find too much opinions and information about this topic.

So in docker there is actual docker version, docker version of thee yml file and docker-compose version.

Lets say I have a docker-compose.yml file within it set on version "3", but the docker-compose version is 1.25 (the latest is 2.13). Okay, so the code is right, using the "deploy" and "resources" keys I was trying to limit the containers memory.

Now the problem is, when you try to do those methods of limiting, it says docker-compose version is outdated or doesnt support such stuff. Checking with the "docker-compose -v" it says 1.25.

In order to limit the memory of the container, it seems I will need to upgrade to 2.13 docker-compose, but the main question is **how does the docker-compose version impact and effect the code in docker-compose.yml file and does it at all?**

I have not tried yet anything, since its kind of a tricky thing to do on a development server which is constantly being bombarded with pr's.

Comment: With each docker compose version comes its own specification, sometimes some are deprecated, sometimes some are added: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix. There is a table of comparison for the version vs specification: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix

Comment: Dont think you got my point and question here, I am asking if docker-compose version has impact on the code within the docker-compose.yml file. 

In docker-compose.yml file you have file versioning 3, but docker-compose is currently sitting at version 1.25 instead of a newest one which is 2.13. 

Its two different things, and there is no much explanations how does one affect another.

Comment: Did you took the time to read the documentation I linked? _In addition to Compose file format versions shown in the table, the Compose itself is on a release schedule, as shown in Compose releases, but file format versions do not necessarily increment with each release. For example, Compose file format 3.0 was first introduced in Compose release 1.10.0, and versioned gradually in subsequent releases._

Comment: _We recommend keeping up-to-date with newer releases as much as possible. However, if you are using an older version of Docker and want to determine which Compose release is compatible, refer to the Compose release notes._